# Can not get data with etcdctl but Can do with curl

Tags: etcd

I can get data from etcd with curl, like follow:

```
core ~ $ curl http://10.12.1.105:2379/v2/keys/zk/codis/db_test
       {"action":"get","node":   {"key":"/zk/codis/db_test","dir":true,"expiration":"2016-09-   18T06:35:35.892545267Z","ttl":31535019,"nodes":    [{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/ActionResponse","dir":true,"expiration":"2016-09-   18T06:40:45.162912721Z","ttl":31535328,"modifiedIndex":10,"createdIndex":10},
{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/LOCK","dir":true,"expiration":"2016-09-18T06:48:07.460467703Z","ttl":31535770,"modifiedIndex":5130,"createdIndex":5130},
{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/servers","dir":true,"modifiedIndex":5132,"createdIndex":5132},
{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/dashboard","value":"{\"addr\": \"10.12.1.101:18087\", \"pid\": 9}","expiration":"2016-09-18T06:35:35.90202187Z","ttl":31535019,"modifiedIndex":6,"createdIndex":6},{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/migrate_tasks","dir":true,"expiration":"2016-09-18T06:35:35.909309855Z","ttl":31535019,"modifiedIndex":7,"createdIndex":7},
{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/slots","dir":true,"modifiedIndex":8,"createdIndex":8},
{"key":"/zk/codis/db_test/actions","dir":true,"expiration":"2016-09-18T06:40:45.15502607Z","ttl":31535328,"modifiedIndex":9,"createdIndex":9}],"modifiedIndex":5,"createdIndex":5}}
```

But I Can not get data from etcd2 with etcdctl :

```
core@hack-day-master ~ $ etcdctl -C 10.12.1.105:2379 ls
/coreos.com
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Try `--no-sync`. If that helps, your etcd cluster membership is messed up. At least, the leader does not have the data your local proxy has.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
etcdctl -C 10.12.1.105:2379 ls --recursive
```

**--recursive** would help list all keys.

Comment: recursive or not, my ls comes back empty. For some reason, using `etcdctl [...] get /openshift.io --prefix --keys-only` seems work ...

Comment: yeah, that's etcd v3 client's command. You can use `etcdctl version` to see that. `--recursive` is applied to v2's etcdctl.